# Python class attribute not printing

Tags: python

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/grant/PycharmProjects/untitled2/venv/gfcdjgh.py", line 12, in <module>
    main()

  File "C:/Users/grant/PycharmProjects/untitled2/venv/gfcdjgh.py", line 10, in main
    print (self.strengthPts)

NameError: name 'self' is not defined

Process finished with exit code 1
```

```
class Superhero:

    def __init__(self, name, strengthPts):
     # Create a new contact with name and phone.
        self.name = name
        self.strengthPts = strengthPts
        self.intelligencePts = intelligencePts

def main():
     print (self.strengthPts)

main()
```

Comment: `self`is defined in `__init__` but not in `main`.

Comment: You need to initialise the class first.

Answer (score 1):

Your `main` method is not in the `Superhero` class, so `self` doesn't exist. If you want to access an object's parameter, *first* create the object and set its parameters, and *after that* you can access them. Example:

```py
spiderman = Superhero('Spider Man', 100, 100)
spiderman.strengthPts # will return his strength points
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a `Superhero` instance:

```
def main():
     sh = Superhero("foo", 123)
     print(sh.strengthPts)
```

Note that `self` is *local* variable. It is not defined outside of the methods. The instance (here: `sh`) on which the method is called is passed to the method as the first argument (`self`, but could be any identifier really).

Answer (score 0):

Your supposed to run superhero and save in a variable like `s = Superhero('Batman',100,200)`. Then access the `strengthPts` from the variable. Your code will look like this:

```
class Superhero:

    def __init__(self, name, strengthPts,intelligencePts):
        self.name = name
        self.strengthPts = strengthPts
        self.intelligencePts = intelligencePts#This was missing

s = Superhero('Spiderman',100,200)

def main():
     print (s.strengthPts)
main()
```